# How to override what's printed for lldb po command, for a swift enum?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, lldb

This issue is caused by the debugger printing the associated values assigned to an enum.  Is there a way to prevent this when you have a custom description?  For this trivial example it's not a big deal, but if you have dictionaries or other large objects it can really pollute the `po` output.

I have a simple swift enum.  I'm trying to override what it prints when doing the `po` command in the debugger.  However, lldb is printing the object's `description` and then a dump of the enum.  For example, given the following code:

```
enum TestEnum : CustomStringConvertible {
    case Value1(test:Int)

    var description: String {
        return "Test Enum"
    }
}
```

When I try to print the object of type TestEnum, or when it's nested in another object that is bring printed, I get this type of output:

```
(lldb) po testEnum
▿ Test Enum
  - Value1 : 1000
```

I just want *my* description to be printed when the object is displayed in the debugger.  I also tried doing this through `debugDescription` with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you as stating?  In the debugger I asked to "po response.value!"  which is of type optional<JSONResult>.  In another example, I also tried to override debugDescription, but got the same result.  So far as I can tell, lldb is printing the custom description and then still doing its internal default printing for the enum.

Comment: Yea, thanks for pointing that out.  I decided to scrap the previous example and pasted in a simplified example.  That helped me determine what it is doing.  It's printing the value for each assigned value associated with the enum.  This is what I wanted to try and prevent.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. The simplified example without dependencies constitutes a MCVE and gives me something to sink my teeth into. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges, to some extent. `po` and CustomStringConvertible aren't really very closely related.

CustomStringConvertible and `description` dictate what you see when you convert the object to a String (hence the name). So in the debugger what you want to do is say `po String(testEnum)`. (Or don't use lldb at all; just print to the console from the running program, using `print(testEnum)`; that's really what CustomStringConvertible is for.)

The display when you say `po testEnum` has to do with how the enum is *reflected*. If you don't like that, you would want to implement CustomReflectable — but I don't believe you really want to do that, as I shall argue in a moment. First, an example:

```
enum TestEnum : CustomStringConvertible, CustomReflectable {
    case Value1(test:Int)

    var description: String {
        return "Test Enum"
    }

    func customMirror() -> Mirror {
        return Mirror(reflecting:self.description)
    }

}
```

Now `po testEnum` will yield `Test Enum`. But... why? Do you really want to throw away the splendid mirroring that an enum gives you nowadays? For the whole first year of Swift's life, we complained that `po` on an enum gave no information at all, not even what case it was; here you are learning not only the case but also the associated value of that case. It seems terribly retrograde, not to say self-defeating, to want to eliminate that.

Comment: One of the associated values was a dictionary that could be rather large when it was displayed.  I used the custom description to printed the contents of this Dictionary nicely.  The default printing of the dictionary was ugly and hard to read.  So basically, when printed, I would see one nicely formatted print  followed by a really ugly one.  Aka, the object was being printed twice.

Comment: I'm I bit concerned about implementing a customMirror just to have nice output in the debugger.  So probably won't do that approach. but many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend saying `po String(...)` and just move on. :)

Comment: Or don't `po` at all. `p` gives a much nicer result if you don't want to see the mirroring.